# pfSense failover and OpenVPN site-to-site

Tags: openvpn, failover, pfsense

I have two pfSense Clusters, and am trying to connect them with an OpenVPN site-to-site VPN. Initially, the client was a single pfSense system, and all was well. Now that one system is a cluster, and the OpenVPN site-to-site would go down on a regular and cyclical basis with a ping restart.

After much hair-pulling, it turned out that the problem was the secondary client. The server (cluster) was configured not to allow duplicate CNs to connect.

Apparently, in a cluster, running services are mirrored. Thus, two OpenVPN servers are actually running - and two OpenVPN clients. Turning off the secondary OpenVPN client was insufficient: next pfsync, it restarts. Disconnecting the external network fixed it.

The "new" pfSense cluster (client) is v2.1.4; the "old" pfSense cluster (server) is v2.1.3.

When I turn on the Duplicate CN option on the server (v2.1.3) I get this error:

`openvpn[41232]: Options error: --duplicate-cn requires --mode server`

When I added `mode server` to the the Advanced Settings section of the server, the site-to-site VPN worked.

Question is this: Is it feasible to have OpenVPN failover? Do I want both clients to be running? Will having both server (or client) nodes running OpenVPN cause troubles? I read that OpenVPN failover is not possible - but pfSense is acting like it is.

**UPDATE:** We're using OpenVPN for site-to-site as that was what was set up in the beginning, and using IPSec wasn't considered. It's still a possibility in the future.

We have this now:

`M1 -+         +- Q1
    |         |
    +---inet--+
    |         |
M2 -+         +- Q2`

Before M2 was brought up, the OpenVPN to Q1/Q2 worked fine.

It's been trouble since. I've heard that OpenVPN doesn't handle failover - and also that mixing IPsec and OpenVPN on the same pfSense system is a bad idea. If I could phase in IPsec I'll bet that would improve matters. (I control all four endpoints by the way.)

**UPDATE 2** Tried enabling "Duplicate Connections" ... that actually turned out to actually shutdown the link invisibly (everything appeared normal). Disabling that made things flow again. What am I missing?

Comment: Why OpenVPN and not IPsec for a site-to-site tunnel?

Comment: Can you diagram this out a little bit?  I have a system of pfSense boxes that I BELIEVE is similar to what you have, but I'm having a little trouble visualizing.  We use IPSEC for site-to-site as well, but we use OpenVPN for "road warrior"-ing in.  Your usage of cluster is throwing me off a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with mixing IPsec and OpenVPN, nor is there a problem doing OpenVPN with HA. When using OpenVPN client instances on an HA pair, you must bind them to a CARP IP so they only run when CARP has master status.

Comment: There's no way to bind a client to a port that I am aware of. Both of the clients connect to the HA OpenVPN server on the cluster address. The problem is with the clients, not the server (although the server might have the solution)... Likely to try IPsec this weekend.

Comment: The "interface" box determines what IP is bound, that's where you pick the CARP IP.

Trust me...I only founded pfSense and literally wrote the book on it.

Comment: Cool! Found it... was bound to the WAN interface. I'll test it out when things settle... Thanks for the help!